# Duplicate parameter output in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

Update:
I'm starting to wonder if this is due to a bug:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/590

But the workaround suggested there does not seem to solve my problem.

---

I am using Swashbuckle to generate API documentation for a C# ASP.NET Web API project.

My target is to allow the following as valid URL:

```
/endpoint/items/123/foo?param2=bar
```

With a required parameter (param1) set to "foo" and an optional parameter (param2) set to "bar". I would like both parameters contained inside a single C# parameter object. (with other optional parameters like param3 and so on). Several endpoints will use identical parameters and I would like to have a single object representing the parameters.

The details of Swagger/Swashbuckle are mostly a black box to be, and I'm unable to figure this out. I'm getting duplicates in the parameter list.

Sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
    // This endpoint is generating documentation the way I would like.
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("endpoint1/items/{id}/{param1}")]
    public string GetDataForParameters(int id, string param1, string param2 = null, string param3 = null)
    {
        return string.Format("Params: {1}, {2}, {3}", id, param1, param2, param3);
    }

    // This endpoint has the structure I would like, but I get duplicates for param1 in the documentation.
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("endpoint2/items/{id}/{param1}")]
    public string GetDataForParameters(int id, [FromUri(Name = "")]MyParams myParams)
    {
        return string.Format("Params: {1}, {2}, {3}", id, myParams.Param1, myParams.Param2, myParams.Param3);
    }

    public class MyParams
    {
        public string Param1 { get; set;}
        public string Param2 { get; set;}
        public string Param3 { get; set;}
    }
```

With the second method, I receive the parameters inside a single object. But Swagger displays a duplicate entry for the "param1".

Screenshot: [Swagger duplicate parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwGsM.png)

How can I make Swagger/Swashbuckle not display the second entry for "param1"?

---

The reason for having this structure is that I have multiple endpoints that return different types of data, but they use common parameters.
Some of the parameters are required (and a prt of the ID) so we would like to include those in the URL, with optional parameters in the querystring.
I would prefer the common parameter object should include both required and optional parameters.

Sample code created with Visual Studio 2015 update 1. Default ASP.NET Web API project. Adding the code above to the generated ValuesController.cs. Installed package Swashbuckle 5.3.1 + dependencies.

Comment: second router contains `param1` as a query string as well as a member of `MyParams`. May be this is the reason.

Comment: This is correct - I would like param1 to be specified in the URL path and param2 to be in the querystring. Will update the question to clarify this.

Comment: Update: Deleted my own answer suggesting JsonIgnore as a workaround. This caused Swagger to look correct, but upon further inspection I noticed that the generated URL becomes `/endpoint2/items/123/{Param1}?param1=foo&param2=bar` which is a no-go. I am still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: The behaviour you are experiencing is because of duplicate routes.
Why do you have a route param1 and a query parameter "param1" in the same route?

Comment: I belive this would be fixed if you changed the name of query parameter "param1" to actually be "param2" as param1 is already specified in the route

Comment: @VisualBean: Thanks for replying. Note that the routing works fine, but the documentation is not the way I expected.
If you mean the URL in my comment above, that's a part of my problem: an invalid route generated by Swagger/Swashbuckle.

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment, I didn't read the code correctly :) Have you tried setting param1 from the MyParams class to [required] ?  swagger looks for json annotations to see wether a param is required or not when using an "input object" so to speak

Comment: Tried to use [Required] now, the duplicate also becomes required - but is still a duplicate.

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#remove-duplicate-path-parameters) to be working. I only had to tweak it for case insensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

Update:
Found a workaround. It's ugly:

1. Introduce an explicit duplicate parameter in the method.
2. Add JsonIgnore attribute to the duplicate properties in the parameter object.

Swagger will then pick up the method parameter and documentation for this one. ASP.Net will assign parameters to BOTH the method parameter and the parameter object, allowing the code to use the parameter object.

```
    /// <param name="param1">URL parameters must be documented on this level.</param>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("endpoint2/items/{id}/{param1}")]
    public string GetDataForParameters(int id, string param1, [FromUri(Name = "")]MyParams myParams)
    {
        // the param1 method parameter is a dummy, and not used anywhere.
        return string.Format("Params: {1}, {2}, {3}", id, myParams.Param1, myParams.Param2, myParams.Param3);
    }

    public class MyParams
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Cannot add documentation here, it will be ignored.
        /// </summary>
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Param1 { get; set;}
        /// <summary>
        /// This is included. Querystring parameters can be documented in this class.
        /// </summary>
        public string Param2 { get; set;}
        public string Param3 { get; set;}
    }
```

I will not use this approach, it will be too confusing for any other developer reading the code. So unfortunately, Swagger/Swashbuckle has in pratice forced me to change my (fully working) code in order to generate documentation.

Unless anyone can suggest a proper solution I think the best solution is to have plain method parameters.

Comment: Your workaround worked for me. To get the swashbuckle documentation to work the params are case sensitive. Your route value on the action should be changed to this [Route("endpoint2/items/{id}/{Param1}")]

Answer (score 0):

When Swashbuckle generates its swagger.json file it looks at routing and query parameters
So when you use `Get(string param1, string param2 ..)` that automatically tells Swashbuckle that those parameters are required (because they are NOT set to `= null`)

When using `Get([FromUri(Name = "")]MyParams myParams)`
Swashbuckle looks for data annotations(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) in your model, to tell wether or not a parameter is required or not.

Set Param1 to be required

```
public class MyParams
    {
        [Required]
        public string Param1 { get; set;}
        public string Param2 { get; set;}
        public string Param3 { get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: This makes the duplicate also display as required, but Swagger still display it as a duplicate and generates route similar to `/{Param1}?param1=bar&param1=bar`

Comment: starting to worry this is a deeper issue, updating my question with links.

Comment: @PMBjornerud why is param1 part of the model when it is already in the routing parameters? if you don't mind me asking

Comment: I want a route parameter bound to a property of a parameter object.
If I bind it to a parameter variable, it works. But through a parameter object the documentation gets weird. Note my update and link, seems someone had a working API that broke (this january). I'll investigate that further tomorrow.