# Duplicate parameters output through Swashbuckle/Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

Code is further down in the post.

**Question**: I would like Swashbuckle to generate the following two "GET" requests:

```
 1. mydomain.com/api/books?apikey=12345567891011121314151617181920 
 2. mydomain.com/api/books/1234?apikey=12345567891011121314151617181920
```

Swashbuckle does fine on #1 and it works great from the Swagger UI. But for #2, it ends up generating (and calling):

```
mydomain.com/api/books/{Id}?id=1234&apikey==12345567891011121314151617181920
```

Needless to say, that GET fails. Swashbuckle is picking up the literal "Id" from the route attribute as well as the BookDetail object. In fact, it shows both IDs in the UI, but I was able to solve that by de-duping by hooking up a custom IOperationFilter, but that obviously didn't help with correcting the actual GET request path.

I already looked at [Duplicate parameter output in Swagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478197/duplicate-parameter-output-in-swagger) but that answer does not work for me. I am looking for having Swashbuckle use the "Id" that's part of the BookDetail object so that Swagger UI shows the description (from the XML comment) while supporting route based ID rather than query string based: **mydomain.com/api/books/1234...**. What am I doing wrong? (I am on Swashbuckle 5.2.2).

**Code**:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Books controller
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns books matching the search query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchRequest"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("books")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(BookSearch searchRequest)
    {
        //Do stuff with request

        return Ok();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retruns a single book for the given ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="detailRequest"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("books/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(BookDetail detailRequest)
    {
        //Do stuff with request

        return Ok();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Book search
    /// </summary>
    public class BookSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// API key
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Search terms
        /// </summary>
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Book detail
    /// </summary>
    public class BookDetail
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// API key
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string ApiKey { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Book of the ID you want to retrieve
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Boolean indicating whether to include photos or not
        /// </summary>
        public bool IncludePhotos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#remove-duplicate-path-parameters)? I only had to tweak it for case insensitivity.